# Ошибка в работе скрипта JQuery (uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток.

На странице есть

```html
<div class="form-select" id="0">
<select name="select-category" id="select-category" onchange="selectCategory(this.id)">
...
</select>
```

В него выгружаются главные категории. При выборе одной из них - я передаю значение на сервер через ajax, и после получения json - создаю ещё один селектор (в этом селекторе дочерние категории), помещенный в такой же div, но с значением атрибута id больше на единицу и т.д.

При изменении выбора в select на любом уровне, я получаю атрибут id у .form-select, в который он завернут, после чего прохожусь по всем .form-select, и если у них id больше, то удаляю их.

```js
 ...
 var parent = $('#' + name_id_category).parent();
 var parent_id = parent.attr('id');
 
 $('.form-select').each(function (i) {
     if (parseInt($('.form-select')[i].attributes.id.value) > parent_id) {
     $('.form-select')[i].remove();
     }
 });
 ...
```

Но это работает не правильно. После выбора нескольких категорий (на странице 4 селектора), я меняю самый первый из них, удаляются все, кроме предпоследнего, в консоли ошибка:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

P.S. Уже очень долго парюсь над этим и конкретно так встрял. Возможно мое решение в целом неудачное, буду рад совету и помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во-первых, перестаньте писать костыли вида `onchange` в html-коде. jquery явно не для этих целей создавался, а чтобы наоброт оделить js от верстки.
во-вторых, ваши номера в id это по сути данные, а не идентификатор. Вот и используйте для хранения `data-` атрибуты.  То есть:

```
<div class="form-select" data-id="0">
```

дайте всем своим селектам класс `.select-category`
добавьте обработчик стандартным для jquery путем

```
$(document).on('change', '.select-category', function(){
    ...
});
```

где вместо `document` вы используете ближайшего подходящего общего предка для всех ваших селектов.

Далее при смене селекта берете ближайший `.form-select` и его id и фильтруете все, что не подходит по условию. затем удаляете.

```
let fsId = $(this).closest('.form-select').data('id');
$('.form-select').filter(function(el){ 
                     return $(el).data('id') > fsId; 
                  })
                 .remove();
```

в принципе не было бы ошибкой, наверное, и просто удалить все подходящие, которые стоят позже в DOM, вроде такого

```
let idx = $(".form-select").index($(this));
$(".form-select").gt(idx).remove();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Завтра перепишу по вашему совету и отпишу сюда - что получилось. Пока, временно, смог исправить свою проблему немного другим путем.